# How to use jspdf-autotable in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I was able to import jsPDF, however I can't use autoTable method from jspdf-autotable, not sure how to import it as a dependency of jsPDF.

```
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';

import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import { autoTable } from 'jspdf-autotable';

@Injectable()
export class PdfService {

    constructor() {

    }

    convertJsonToPdf(columns: any, jsonData: any) {
       var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');  // OK, created
       doc.autoTable(columns, jsonData); // Fails because autoTable is not in doc
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to replace this line `import { autoTable } from 'jspdf-autotable';` with `import 'jspdf-autotable';`;

Comment: @SimonBengtsson It worked, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extracted from discussion above, replace this line:

```
import { autoTable } from 'jspdf-autotable';
```

with

```
import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

Comment: what about the angular2? Either import 'jspdf-autotable'; or import { autoTable } from 'jspdf-autotable';  nothing is working

Comment: `import 'jspdf-autotable';` should work. Feel free to write a new question with more information if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344349/property-autotable-does-not-exist-on-type-jspdf this is the exact question

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring like:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

it is better to do this

```
import 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
declare let jsPDF;
```

This is how I solved the problem.