# Property 'autoTable' does not exist on type jsPDF

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using `angular2` and `Node JS`. I have installed [jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) and [jspdf-autotable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-autotable) both modules using `npm`.
In angular-cli.json file, I have embedded the scripts:

```
"scripts": [ 
        "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
      ],
```

In my `component.ts` file , I have imported these files as follows:

```
 import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'; 
 import * as autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable';
```

I have also tried these lines to import `jspdf-autotable`

```
import { autoTable } from 'jspdf-autotable'; 
import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

But nothing is working.

In function of `component.ts` file I am using sample code as follows:

```
var columns = ["ID", "Country", "Rank", "Capital"];
        var data = [
            [1, "Denmark", 7.526, "Copenhagen"],
            [2, "Switzerland",  7.509, "Bern"],
            [3, "Iceland", 7.501, "Reykjavík"],
            [4, "Norway", 7.498, "Oslo"],
            [5, "Finland", 7.413, "Helsinki"]
        ];
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.autoTable(columns, data);
        doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

But now when I run the node command to start app then during compilation I am getting error as:

> Property 'autoTable' does not exist on type 'jsPDF'.

Can any one please suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer:

No need to import jspdf or jspdf-autotable in component.ts file.

component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
declare let jsPDF;
```

In my case

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [305, 250]);

var options1 = {
   padding: 50
};

doc.addHTML($('#riskdate_heading'),0,10,options1 ,() => {

   doc.addHTML($('#risktitle'),0,30,options1, () => {

     var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("riskTable"));

                var header = function(data) {
                    doc.setFontSize(18);
                    doc.setTextColor(40);
                    doc.setFontStyle('normal');
                };

                var riskoptions = {
                                    tableWidth: 'auto',
                                    addPageContent: header,
                                    margin: {  top: 10, horizontal: 7 },
                                    startY:  50,
                                    columnStyles: {0: {columnWidth: 'wrap'}}
                                };

                doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, riskoptions);

                doc.save("table.pdf");
        });
    });
```

Comment: I am getting error :- `doc.autoTableHtmlToJson` is not a function . Can anyone help me ?

Comment: try to import with the following code: var jsPDF = require('jspdf');
require('jspdf-autotable');

Answer (score 12):

The following worked for me in Angular 11, jsPDF 2.3.1, jspdf-autotable 3.5.14:

```js
import jsPDF from 'jspdf'
import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable'
  
public printTable() {

    const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4'); 
    
    const head = [['ID', 'Country', 'Index', 'Capital']]
    const data = [
        [1, 'Finland', 7.632, 'Helsinki'],
        [2, 'Norway', 7.594, 'Oslo'],
        [3, 'Denmark', 7.555, 'Copenhagen'],
        [4, 'Iceland', 7.495, 'Reykjavík'],
        [5, 'Switzerland', 7.487, 'Bern'],
        [9, 'Sweden', 7.314, 'Stockholm'],
        [73, 'Belarus', 5.483, 'Minsk'],
    ]

    autoTable(doc, {
        head: head,
        body: data,
        didDrawCell: (data) => { },
    });

    doc.save('table.pdf');
}
```

Comment: I am using the same approach, however, I still can't seem to use autoTable.previous.finalY. Any ideas?

Comment: data should'nt be an array, after that it works above.

Answer (score 6):

```
 var columns = ['ID', 'Country', 'Rank', 'Capital'];
var data = [
  [1, 'Denmark', 7.526, 'Copenhagen'],
  [2, 'Switzerland', 7.509, 'Bern'],
  [3, 'Iceland', 7.501, 'Reykjavík'],
  [4, 'Norway', 7.498, 'Oslo'],
  [5, 'Finland', 7.413, 'Helsinki'],
];
var doc = new jsPDF();
```

> the Magic Here (doc as any)

```
(doc as any).autoTable(columns, data);
doc.save('angular-demo.pdf');
```

Answer (score 5):

For those people who are using angular 6/7 try to do the following:

Instead of just use this:

```
declare var jsPDF: any;
```

Try this:

```
declare const require: any;
const jsPDF = require('jspdf');
require('jspdf-autotable');
```

It works fine to me.

Comment: Hey I tried this and am getting a Cannot set property 'autoTableText' of undefined error.

Comment: Sorry i was inactive from few days, Did you solved the issue? @CodeMan03

Answer (score 2):

assuming this is a typescript issue and you have `@types/jspdf` installed as a devDependency you just need to extend jsPDF types...

```
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
import { UserOptions } from 'jspdf-autotable';

interface jsPDFCustom extends jsPDF {
    autoTable: (options: UserOptions) => void;
}

const doc = new jsPDF() as jsPDFCustom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you have to use jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js along with jspdf.js to work.
Here is the github link you can refer to https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable
Sample from above link.

```
    // app.component.ts or any other component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare
var jsPDF: any; // Important

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';

    constructor() {
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
        doc.autoTable(columns, data);
        doc.save("table.pdf");
    }
}
```

Updated Sample:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var jsPDF: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'app';
  constructor() { 
    console.log('hi i m constr');
    var test = new jsPDF();
    console.dir(test.autoTable);
  }

}
```

Comment: I have used the same plugin which you are referring. but it is showing same error.

Comment: Ok, let me check once more

Comment: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/297 I have also put the question there

Comment: Yeah right I am also trying a sample not able to make it work.

Comment: If you use 'declare var jsPDF: any;' instead of import statements it works. I think jsPDF is a global object so we have to use this statement instead of imports

Comment: also same thing is mentioned is the github sample also.